# How to understand transfer of momentum between motorcycle seat and rider?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, momentum, acceleration

I have an app that samples acceleration at a motorbike seat. I want to be able to compare how comfortable these accelerations feel for two different motorcycles.

Let's say I have the following scenarios:

1. A 75 kg rider on **300 kg** motorcycle experiencing vertical acceleration of 1g from the seat
2. A 75 kg rider on **100 kg** motorcycle experiencing
   vertical acceleration of 1g from the seat

**Will the subjective experience of the rider on both bikes be identical?** 
- OR -

**Will the heavier bike feel stronger because it transfers more momentum to the rider?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mass of the motorcycle is irrelevant. If the motorcycle (and hence rider) is experiencing the same acceleration, then they will "feel" the same thing. The rider will have the same momentum in either case.

The difference just comes into how much force is needed from the motor for the same acceleration. More mass means more force is needed.